# How to find which pom item introduces a specific external dependency?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I want to find which pom item imports the following nacos-api:1.0.0

[image]

I thought it is this item which depends on it

[image]

but the details of it is as below:

[image]

so it is probably not? are there any ways to find which pom item introduces a specific external dependency, especially on IDEA?

maven tree doesn't help

```
    mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=nacos-client:1.0.0
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building user 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:tree (default-cli) @ user ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.172 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-30T03:06:07+08:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 37M/361M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Dependency tree might help: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: There is tab (on the bottom) on the pom.xml file in IDEA which is marked "Dependency Analyzer" which can show you where it's coming from...or command line via maven-dependency-plugin:tree will work also...If you haven't yet installed that plugin (`Maven Helper`) in IDEA I strongly recommend to do so ...

Comment: Linke to the plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to know where(which pom item) is the `nacos-api:1.0.0` from, not where is the pom item from. also, as updated in the question content, maven tree doesn't help

Comment: @lily Please try `mvn dependency:tree` with correct parameters. First of all, leave out `-Dverbose` because it leads to unreliable results. Secondly, `includes` needs to follow the syntax `[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]`.

Comment: @lily Not written as that. Just use https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.alibaba.nacos%20a:nacos-api. you see a number of versions. A litte bit search via google and github you will find: https://github.com/xkcoding/nacos (Thanks for doing your work).

Comment: @khmarbaise seems you misunderstood my question. I'm asking which pom item of my pom file depends on this `nacos-api:1.0.0`. I'm not asking where to find it.

Comment: As already mentioned see my first and second comment. You dependencies don't do that but the one you are using (so called transitive dependencies)...

Comment: @lily Your `includes` is still missing the groupId and type. It would probably be easier to just leave out the `includes` and then search through the dependency tree to find the places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such single action. But it is possible to find the corresponding for the library pom with these steps:

1. <kbd>F4</kbd> (**Go to source** action) on selected item in External library will open this library configuration dialog:

[image]

2. Then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (**Find usages** action) to show the module where this library is used:

[image]

3. Then you can find this module in Maven tool window (use [speed search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html) for example to locate it more easily), select it in the tree and navigate to corresponding pom using <kbd>F4</kbd> (**Go to source** action) again:

[image]